# LEFT JOIN two columns from one table on two separate tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm not sure if this is possible exactly as stated in the title, but what I'm trying to accomplish, however possible, is what would amount to left joining two columns from one table, each on a separate table.

Here's the statement I'm working with.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't allow me to actually do this and gives me an error message.  Is there another way to accomplish what I want?  Is my syntax perhaps just off?

```
select h.HITTER_ID, u.UMPIRE_ID, u.HAND_B
from
hitters h,
schedules sched
LEFT JOIN
umpires u
ON sched.home_base_umpire_id = u.UMPIRE_ID and h.HAND_B = u.HAND_B
```

In the umpires table, each UMPIRE_ID appears twice, once with HAND_B = "R" and once with HAND_B = "L"

Essentially, I want to:

1) Pull the UMPIRE_ID from umpires when that UMPIRE_ID appears in schedules

2) Of the two UMPIRE_ID records, select the one with the HAND_B field that corresponds to the HAND_B field in hitters

I could put the "h.HAND_B = u.HAND_B" in the where clause, but that would require that the UMPIRE_ID not be NULL, and I need to leave open the possibility that it is NULL.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query to be like below

```
select h.HITTER_ID, 
u.UMPIRE_ID, 
u.HAND_B
from hitters h
left join umpires u on h.HAND_B = u.HAND_B
left join schedules sched ON sched.home_base_umpire_id = u.UMPIRE_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Rahul. Sorry I'm just circling back to this now. I've tried the change you proposed, but it still doesn't quite accomplish what I'm looking to do. In this example, it's only pulling records from "schedules" if sched.home_base_umpire_id matches to a corresponding UMPIRE_ID in "umpires." If all sched.home_base_umpire_id are NULL, no results are returned, which is bad. I want all records from schedules to be pulled no matter what and to only pull records from umpires if there is a match. Is there a way to re-work this query to allow for this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Essentially, @rahul, all records from schedules and from hitters will be pulled, but I only want records from umpires to be pulled where the UMPIRE_ID matches to schedules and where the HAND_B matches to hitters

Comment: I've tried changing the second left join to a right join, which seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  It continues to act as if both are left joins.

select h.HITTER_ID, 
u.UMPIRE_ID, 
u.HAND_B
from hitters h
left join umpires u on h.HAND_B = u.HAND_B
right join schedules sched ON sched.home_base_umpire_id = u.UMPIRE_ID;